# Two-way binding issue - PropertyChanged & CanExecuteChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, mvvm

I want to implement that when a textbox value is changed, my Add button become available.

I bind the textbox with viewModel:

```
<TextBox Name="nameTbx" Text="{Binding Path=NewNode.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

My button:

```
<Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding Path=AddNewNodeProperty}"/>
```

In the XAML code behind i set the DataContext to my ViewModel. ViewModel looks like:

```
/* code*/

private Node _newNode = new Node();
public Node NewNode
{
    get
    {
        return _newNode;
    }
    set
    {
        _newNode = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("NewNode");
    }
}

private AddNode _addNewNodeProperty;
    public AddNode AddNewNodeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _addNewNodeProperty;
        }
    }
```

In a constructor i initialize the _addNewNodeProperty

```
this._addNewNodeProperty = new AddNode(this);
```

Here is my AddNode class:

```
public class AddNode : ICommand
{
    private ServiceMapViewModel viewModel;

    public AddNode(ServiceMapViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
        this.viewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
            {
                CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        };
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        bool b = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.viewModel.NewNode.Name);

        return b;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.viewModel.AddNewNode();
    }
}
```

And finally my Node class:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }

    public Group Group { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public string Metadata { get; set; }

    public List<string> Children = new List<string>();

    public List<string> Parents = new List<string>();
}
```

The problem is that when i change my textbox text, NewNode is getting the value for me, but it supposed to set .

Tnx in advanced!

**EDIT**
Let me add something:

I also have a datagrid on the screen and when Selected Item is changed, my Add butom become available.

Selected Item:

```
<DataGrid Name="nodeDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyServiceMap.Nodes}"
        Background="Silver" Margin="0,34,10,10" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedNode}"  >
```

And VM:

```
private Node _selectedNode = new Node();
    public Node SelectedNode
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedNode;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedNode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedNode");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TextBox is bound to the `Name` property of your `Node` object. The `Name` property does not raise a `PropertyChanged` event when it changes. Only the entire `NewNode` property will raise the event when it is changed.

**Edit to offer a suggestion**

One approach would be to create a `NodeViewModel` class which, as *mtaboy* suggested, would implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You would create whatever properties on the ViewModel that you would want to expose to your user. You can think of the ViewModel as sitting between your Model (i.e., `Node` class) and your View (the UI shown to the user).

One change I would recommend would be to encapsulate the `ICommand` logic into its own class. The one I often use is the `RelayCommand` class which can be found in Josh Smith's [MVVM article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) on MSDN. If you use that class, you can define either a property or a private method in your ViewModel class which would return whether the user could Add or not. For example,

```
private bool CanAddNewNode()
{
  return !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Name);
}
```

When instantiating your `RelayCommand`, you can pass a lambda for the second parameter that refers to that method above.

```
var saveCommand = new RelayCommand(param => SaveMethod(), param => CanAddNewNode());
```

You would expose an `ICommand` property from your ViewModel which would return the `RelayCommand` object.

Hopefully, that gets you started.

Comment: Updated my answer to offer some concrete suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that when i change my textbox text, NewNode is getting
>   the value for me, but it supposed to set .

I believe you should support `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for the `Node` class as well.

Also if you want keep proeprty synchronized whilst each character update - try out setting UpdateSourceTrigger, otherwise property would be updated on LostFocus event.

```xml
<TextBox Name="nameTbx" 
         Text="{Binding Path=NewNode.Name, 
                        Mode=TwoWay,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: I tried that, but i am reading a data from .XML through WCF and i could not get any data from .XML when i implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Why `could not get any data from .XML when i implement INotifyPropertyChanged.`? Anyway you can work it around by using `NodeUi` class wrapper for `Node` model entity

Answer (score 1):

Your Node Class Must Impliment

> INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class Node:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

       #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
     string _name ;
      public string Name
      {
          get { return _name; }


          set
          {
              _name = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("Name");

          }
      }



.....
```

for more information see [MVVM Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute)

Comment: I tried that, but i am reading a data from .XML through WCF and i could not get any data from .XML when i implement INotifyPropertyChanged...

Comment: I know that for impliment obseverpattern for mvvm you must impliment INotifyPropertyChanged,But see this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87510/WCF-by-Example-Introduction

Comment: Literally saying `class Node:INotifyPropertyChanged` - this is not inheritance, this is an interface implementation

Comment: @sll You are right,I have mistake....but in my above comment i said "you must impliment INotifyPropertyChanged" .